# jQuery dynamic input value lost on blur or focusout

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, dojo, dijit.form

Whenever I dynamically change the value of an `input` field (`$("#test").val("test")` or `$("#test").value = "test"`) then physically click the field then exit the `input` the value reverts back to `""`. Physically changing the value retains the value.

I have tried:

```
- physically removing all event listeners on the page in Chrome DevTools
```

```
- $("input").off();
```

```
- $("input").click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation(); 
    return false;
  });
  $("input").blur(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation(); 
    return false;
  });
  $("input").focusout(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation(); 
    return false;
  });
```

I have checked network traffic and nothing has changed on change.

The system uses React, dojo, dijit if that is relevant / helps.

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue on a new page, or, ideally, in a stack snippet here?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I think there lies the problem. I am having trouble identifying the root cause.

Comment: I don't know enough about [tag:dijit.form], but is it possible that it *replaces* your `<input>` tag with its own UI?  ("dijit contains form *widgets*").  You could try:  `$("input").val("test").change()` to trigger a change event so that the "widget" updates the UI *and* its internal store of the value.  **edit** as described here: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/form.html#id6

Comment: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/form/TextBox.html#dijit-form-textbox suggests: `dijit.byId("your_id").set("test")`

Comment: Thanks for the responses. There is no widgetid so I don't think I can use `dijit.byId` unless I am completely missing the mark.

Comment: I only got that from looking at the digit help pages - perhaps it's not wijit?  Whenever a third part *replaces* your inputs, apply DOM/jquery events to the original elements will have no effect - you need to apply the events to the replacement UI.